# If $X$ is a smooth projective curve and $g(X)=0$, then $X$ is a plane conic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

I've read the following statement in Manin-Tsfasman's [survey](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/76e205349670a1ed8c5942afecf44d08/rm1998.pdf), Proposition 1.1.1 (I'm sorry I could only find the link in Russian):

> Let $X$ be a smooth, projective rational curve over a field $k$. Then $-K_X$ gives an embedding $X\hookrightarrow \Bbb{P}^2$ of $X$ as a degree 2 curve on $\Bbb{P}^2$.

This seems like a classical result, but I don't know how this can be shown.

When $k$ is algebraically closed, I know how to prove even more. Take a point $P\in X$. Since $\deg(P)=1\geq 2g(X)=0$, then by Hartshorne's Corollary 3.2, chapter IV, we have an embedding $X\hookrightarrow \Bbb{P}^1$, which proves $X$ is actually isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1$.

How do we approach this when $k$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Take the anticanonical class and the morphism defined by it; this works over any field.

Comment: @Sasha, in order to show that $-K_X$ defines a morphism $\varphi:X\to\Bbb{P}^2$ I should be able to prove that $h^0(X,-K_X)=3$ and that $\varphi$ is an embedding, right? How do I do that?

Comment: @Sasha and how do I show that $\varphi(X)$ has degree 2?

Comment: @rmdmc89 $\varphi$ has the same degree as the divisor $-K_X$ which induces it and $\deg(-K_X) = -(2g-2) = 2$. The fact that $h^0(X,-K_X)=3$ follows from Riemann-Roch since $h^0(X, mK_X) = 0$ for all $m \geq 1$, so in particular, $h^0(X, K_X - (-K_X)) = 0$.

Comment: @rmdmc89: All these facts can be verified over an algebraic closure of your field, and in this case you can use that $X \cong \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Sasha, you mean that the values of $h^i(X,-K_X)$ are the same as the ones of $h^i(\overline{X},-K_\overline{X})$, where $\overline{X}:=X\times_k\overline{k}$? I can't see why this is so.